# How does the previous floated box affect the next floated box?

Tags: html, css

Two sections of css, 3 boxes in it,only  one difference between css and css2.
In css1 it is `float:left;` for box2, in css2 it is `float:right;` for box2.
Any other css code are the same for css1 and css2.
Here it is my css1.

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    }
div.box{
    width:640px;
    height:800px;
    }
div.box1{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    }
div.box2{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    } 
div.box3{
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="box">
    <div class="box1">box1
    </div>
    <div class="box2">box2
    </div>
    <div class="box3">box3
    </div>
</div>
```

Here it is my css2.

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    }
div.box{
    width:640px;
    height:800px;
    }
div.box1{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    }
div.box2{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:right;
    } 
div.box3{
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="box">
    <div class="box1">box1
    </div>
    <div class="box2">box2
    </div>
    <div class="box3">box3
    </div>
 </div>
```

Only one line of css is different among css1 and css2.
In css1 why `float:left` for box2 in css1 result in a gap between box1 and bo3?
In css2 why `float:right` for box2 in css1 result in no gap between box1 and bo3?
Please point out the css rule
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#float-rules
for the result of css1 and css2.

Comment: You are just updating the question, did my answer clear it? `:)`

Comment: I am searching  z-axis to help me to understand it.

Comment: Ha ha.. That's an imaginary Z Axis... Just for your understanding. I gave it twice. LoL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is space exactly to the height of the `box2` in the first CSS because, both `box2` and `box3` are `float`ed `left`. So consider them being in the same z-axis (just for example).

Now in the second case, the `box1` and `box3` are only `float`ed `left`. So they are in the same plane, while `box2`, floated right, is in another plane.

I suspect, the `float: left` will also `clear: left`.

**Note:** This may not be the exact scenario, but I used `planes` and `z-axis` **just for understanding** in a simpler way.

Comment: I can't find relationship among z-axis and plane and my question.I am sorry to say that there are  analogies and metaphors in explanation of Praveen Kumar ,it make me confused, i want other expert to explain it with more logistic and reasoning .

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I agree. :) Let an expert answer. But did you understand the logic, which I feel might be valid?

Comment: At last i understand explanation of Praveen Kumar.